# Is there any free OCR library for Android?

Tags: android, ocr

I'm looking for a Java OCR that runs on Android, however Asprise doesn't seem to be a platform independent OCR.  is there any opensource/free Java OCR I can use for android application development?

Comment: Google recently released an OCR API: https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Comment: For people who coming from 2021, there is a great library for android/OS : https://developers.google.com/ml-kit

Answer (score 38):

OCR can be pretty CPU intensive, you might want to reconsider doing it on a smart phone.

That aside, to my knowledge the popular OCR libraries are [Aspire](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/index.php?lang=java) and [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr).  Neither are straight up Java, so you're not going to get a drop-in Android OCR library.

However, Tesseract is open source (GitHub hosted infact); so you can throw some time at porting the subset you need to Java.  My understanding is its *not insane* C++, so depending on how badly you need OCR it might be worth the time.

So short answer: No.

Long answer: if you're willing to work for it.

Answer (score 21):

I am having quite a lot of luck with [tesseract-android-tools](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/)

Answer (score 20):

ANother option could be to post the image to a webapp (possibly at a later moment), and have it OCR-processed there without the C++ -> Java port issues and possibly clogging the mobile CPU.

Comment: very good idea :D
I assume you meant a web service (asmx)
thanks

Answer (score 7):

[Google Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/) is the perfect application for doing both OCR and translation.
And the good news is that [Google Goggles to Become App Platform](http://phandroid.com/2010/04/14/google-goggles-to-become-app-platform/).

Until then, you can use [IQ Engines](http://www.iqengines.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is.

But OCR is very vast. I know an Android application that has an OCR feature, but that might not be the kind of OCR you are looking after.

This open-source application is called [Aedict](http://code.google.com/p/aedict/), and it does OCR on handwritten Japanese characters. It is not that slow.

If it is not what you are looking for, please precise which kind of characters, and which data input (image or X-Y touch history).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the google docs [OCR reader](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr).