# Custom Character recognition for android

Tags: android, image-processing

I am looking for a way to recognize a very specific set or images/characters using a android device.

I dont mind doing this either by taking a picture or scanning (not actual scanning , just hovering over a image like how the barcode readers work). Since I have never done this before ,pointers to specific Libs and directions on how things should work would be welcome.

Note : I don't want to recognize barcodes so don't point me to barcode libs unless they support custom images etc.

Comment: you want to have google googles app functionality?

Comment: Nope the images I want to recognize are just letters , but they are not English.

Comment: I think you are looking for an OCR lib.
Check this threads: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971344/java-based-ocr-sdk-api

Comment: the tesseract.jar library supports many languages and supports letters and words