# How to convert image to text converter in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Character recognition for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371107/custom-character-recognition-for-android)

I have some camera shots which contains mainly text. I want to convert 
them to a string format. Can anybody suggest a solution for it? Is there any external library 
available for android?

Comment: This question has been flagged as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371107/808940.  Please use the search to avoid creating duplicate questions.

Comment: Have you tried google goggles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the google docs [OCR reader](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OCR).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an OCR library for Android.

Please refer to [Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)