# Android OCR Library

Tags: android, image-processing, ocr

Does anyone know any available libraries or sample codes that can be used to develop an app that reads the text in an image captured by the camera? Something similar to Google Goggles but only for reading text.

Comment: though the question is closed as "off-topic" it's still useful for the community

Comment: Google recently released an API to achieve this: https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

Comment: I would recommend you to use tesseract-android-tools, tess-two fork specifically.

Link with an OCR example using tess-two: https://solidgeargroup.com/ocr-on-android

Answer (score 16):

1. Look at [ABBYY's Android OCR lib](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android) (paid)
2. [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) JNI wrapper (free)
3. Look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

Comment: Tesseract is now at [Github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

Answer (score 5):

Check out Mezzofanti which uses Tesseract. We used it for our project.

http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/
and
http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzofanti-augmented-reality-through-text-recognition-146.html

/Amoxus

Answer (score 3):

You might try OpenCV to capture images. It supports android. Then you would need some more libraries to process the images. Like [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) but not sure if it would work on andriod

Answer (score 3):

Check out free opensource Tesseract library integration in android application in below URL:

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/