# Library for scanning numbers

Tags: android, android-camera, ocr, scanning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android OCR Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836136/android-ocr-library)

Is there any library for scanning numbers for android? I have an application in that you need to enter 14-length numbers from one ticket, and then click on the OK button. Now I want to enable that users can scan the numbers on the ticket, application will recognize the numbers and put it in the application. I can't use ZXing because it is only for scanning barcode images, is there any other library?

Comment: Why not have the first program create a bar code? Or use technology to directly sent?

Comment: Because I don't make these tickets, and they don't want do cooperate with me.