# Read Image Data

Tags: android, camera

Is there any way to get text data present in .jpeg or .png file which is captured by camera?

For example-

If i captured debit card by device camera then how to get debit card number or card holder name present on it from captured photo.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Comment: pls refer this code : https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836353/4148757 you can use Tesseract-ocr

Comment: @Dixit Patel If i used 2 ViewfinderView in capture layout it gives me nullpointer exception -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, as already suggested above, you are to plunge into the science of *optical recognition*. These are quite complex algorithms that analyze pixels of an image and try to 'see' some text or, let's say, faces in the images. This objective, obvious for a human eye and mind, is quite complex especially considering that the image may have been shot with some particular lighting (back light or side light), with right or wrong white balance, etc.

Despite the whole complexity, there is good news: Google has provided a special library that does exactly that: recognizes texts, bar codes and faces. It is called  [Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/)

Even without knowing the recognizing algorithms, you basically initiate this library and then feed your images to these algorithms with Face API, Barcode API or Text API. And then after the processing within that library you are given whatever was found by those algorithms. It's a kind of Magic :)

Useful links here:

[Tutorial with Text API](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0)

[The code sample of the app using Text API](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/ocr-codelab/ocr-reader-complete)

Comment: Tutorial link is broken!