# Android Number Scanner

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to **scan numbers** by the camera in Android? I found a barcode scanner libraries but they are not what I need.

sample screenshot

[image]

Comment: use google API to convert image to words. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Comment: What you are looking for is called an [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) library. Questions asking for libraries are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836136/android-ocr-library) on stackoverflow, so if you don't get an answer here, do a search for ocr Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [Text Recognition API Overview](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview) to extract the text from the image. Then you can parse the text to extract the numbers.

[Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/) Android Vision team is also providing a codelab to get us started.