# Use Camera to capture Text. Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, google-gears, google-gadget, google-goggles

I want to do something like a Google Googles but use only the Camera to text feature in it. I want to use the camera to take picture of a text image, and convert it into text for use with in a edit text. Is this possible. How to do this?

Any kind of Idea you have related to this would be helpful. Please let me know your ideas. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called OCR.

There's already excellent answers on StackOverflow on how to use OCR libraries for Android.

- [Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

Comment: Did you checked? link is broken.