# Obtaining information from a picture taken with the camera device

Tags: java, android

I started to develope a new application for Android OS and the idea of this application is to find some words from the picture that taken with the camera device.

I don't know how to find words and if it's a long sentence so the application will divide the words.

Does you have some ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [Android GOCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-gocr/develop).

Comment: Thanks but maybe there is something with Java?

Comment: Don't know. There is a question very similar to yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr