# OCR for android

Tags: android, ocr

I am developing an android application in which i am looking for the pattern from camera which is a word of 10 character number or alphabet(just like we see in QR reader).Are there any API's available for it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android OCR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there are no native opensource Java OCR SDKs. There are Java APIs which wrap calls for native interfaces, for example, for one of the most popular opensource OCR engines - Tesseract (http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/) - there are some Java wrappers like tesjeract (http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/) or Tess4J (http://tess4j.sf.net/). That could work for you, but it's rather hard to set up and will require developing image-preprocessing and font training on your side.

One more solution could be a cloud service. It requires end-user application to have the internet connection, but it's independent from your programming language choice and resources limitations. Have a look at [www.ocrsdk.com for ocr in Android](http://ocrsdk.com/producttour/mobile-devices/), it's a cloud-based OCR SDK that let you upload an image through web API and returns you the OCRed data.

This Web API based OCR SDK is not free, which may not be suitable for you, but i still recommend you try it out (it has a free 90 days trial without any upfront charges) as its pricing is really affordable in comparison with enterprise solutions while it provides enterprise-level OCR accuracy which is way better than open source.

You may also find useful this [Android codesample](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/Android) at github (you need to get API key at http://ocrsdk.com to use it). Disclamer: i work @ ABBYY.

Comment: i dont want to use cloud computing in my app thats the thing.i did found many cloud based ocr and that to entirely free. what i am thinking is that rather than developing entirely new ocr if i had some example i can use them as the reference for my code.

Answer (score 2):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr), there are quite a few.

Tesjeract (http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/), a JNI Wrapper for Tesseract (http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/).

Very nice write up on this: http://www.itwizard.ro/interfacing-cc-libraries-via-jni-example-tesseract-163.html

Example of it in practice: Mezzofanti (http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/), an open-source Android App using Tesjeract

Comment: I hate down votes without a reason. I found this article answer helpful +1