# How to convert a drawn image to a character in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to convert the image drawn on a canvas by the user to the corresponding alphabet or numeric . Suppose if the user draws 'a' on the canvas , it should be converted to the proper text character 'a' . Please give some input to proceed in this way .

Comment: check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr) about Android OCR.

Comment: refer this-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string