# Convert x/y coordinates to text

Tags: android, text, ocr

I am attempting to develop an Android app that allows a user to write notes with their finger onto a canvas,

what i would like is to convert these "drawings" x/y coordinates into text.

does anyone know of an open source library that can perform the required conversion?

Comment: Which x/y coordinates are you interested in? Are you allowing the user to draw freely like MSPaint / Skitch? If so, what x/y coordinates do you want?

Comment: in my custom view i obtain the Motion events x and y coordinates from within the onTouch() method. i have a List of Lists holding each "stroke" the user makes on the screen. its these x and y coordinates i would like to convert to text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To create gesture that matches letters:**

You can use the GestureBuilder Sample Project from the SDK.

Do `New Project > Android Sample Project > GestureBuilder ...`

Make sure you installed the available samples from the SDK Manager.

**To recognize gestures:**

Take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html) tutorial.

**About libraries:**

There is some libraries about gesture reconginition out there.
But I don't think there is any library that will convert coordinates directly to a letter.

There is already a build-in gesture recongnotion system in android.

Why not use it ? http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

I hope all this will help you. :)

**EDIT:**

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr) question.

OCR means Optical character recognition. 
This is not exactly what you are looking for, but i thougth you could try to convert gestures to images and then process them with [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

Comment: thanks for your time. Yes OCR isnt really what i need, i threw that in as thats the closest GOOGLE would give me, i hadnt considered "Gestures" at all i will give it a look, thanks again

Comment: i can recognise "most" of the alphabet and numerics, however my users will be forced to enter each letter separately. is it possible to detect "joined up" writing?

Comment: It seems to be kind of a hard task to detect "joined up" writing using only gestures ... Spliting letters will be hard to achieve ... Perhaps you can give OCR a try like I said in my edit. But keep in mind it's going to be a lot more work that using gestures.