# OCR for Symbols

Tags: android, ocr, symbols

I will try to implement OCR on some symbols font (no text, just some symbols). I could read the theory about neural networks and try to implement something myself, but, in order to save time, it would be nice to use an existing library.

Any solutions yet?

It would be used in Android and therefore, Java could be preferred, but in any case I could do it as well with the NDK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr