# Getting Image by Android and get the text from capture image

Tags: android, image-processing

I am trying to make an app to take the image by using android, and then getting the text from the captured image(it might be OCR like). Please help me out on it, if anybody have idea about it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For capturing images you can take a look at this http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html or this http://notes.hfoss.org/index.php/Tutorial:Camera_and_Gallery_Demo.

For OCR you can check this thread [Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr).

Hope this helps.