# OCR code in android platform

Tags: android, open-source, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android OCR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

Currently, I have a project in mobile application. in the application, I would like to developed OCR. Anyone know the sourcecode which can be execute for android platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popular OCR libraries are [Aspire](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/index.php?lang=java) and [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr).

Example of it in practice:
Mezzofanti (http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/), an open-source Android App using Tesjeract.

OCR can be pretty CPU intensive, you might want to reconsider doing it on a smart phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/), this link offers some API for Android.