# Barcode Detection in Android

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, barcode, rectangles

There is a image and the image has a barcode in it like this:

[image]

I do not want to read from a barcode.

My intention is to identify the position of the barcode so that I can detect the information around the barcode. I want to extract V516990 and 2653 positions from this bitmap.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Image processing is a huge area, what have you tried for the barcode so far? Have you seen this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader/   It looks like it may be of help to you, while you won't need the reading part it will find the barcode. Have a look at some OCR too, there's code out there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253028/ocr-code-in-android-platform

Comment: Check this post out-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013703/how-to-find-the-location-of-red-region-in-an-image-using-matlab/9014569#9014569