# how to read business card image and store information into contact?

Tags: java, android, android-image

I have started **Scan Card** Application in Android.which do following task...
**1) Take Photo
2) Scan Photo**

This application will scan all information from image,information like *Contact name,
Phone number,Address,Email address(if available)....etc*

[Scan card app on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.BCRLite&feature=related_apps)

Can any body solve this?

I want to develop this application.Please Reply me if any **API or help** is available.

Comment: you might try this previous topic :
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr

Comment: are you able to make this application?