# How to perform OCR in Android App

Tags: java, android, ocr

This question has been asked before ([Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/is-there-any-free-ocr-library-for-android)) but the answers are pretty old (6 years) and I hope that Optical Character Recognition possibilities have grown by now.

So I would need to extract some text from a photo to perform some analysis on it, for an Android App. I have heard about Google Cloud Vision API but I am not sure this is the best way to do it as it requires internet access for the app...

Do you know if there is any API that would allow this kind of feature for standalone apps ?

Comment: You could try to make Tesseract compatible with Android (although I'm pretty sure that there is an Android development version)

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"